# Can I access IPv4 DNS resolver from IPv6-only network?

Tags: dns, ipv6, ipv4

Everyone knows that it is not possible to run `nslookup` command through an ipv6 resolver with ipv4-only host. For instance the following command will result error on ipv4 host:

```
nslookup facebook.com 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

But my question is if we have an ipv6-only host (not dual-stacked and no NAT64 service enabled) then is it possible to execute `nslookup` command on ipv4 DNS resolver (8.8.8.8 i.e.):

```
nslookup facebook.com 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It doesn't matter whether it's a DNS resolver or something else – you cannot send packets to an IPv4 address if you don't have IPv4 yourself (or access to a NAT64 translator which has IPv4).

---

Although IPv4 *addresses* can be mapped to IPv6 format, this is a local-only feature (i.e. used for configuring dual-stack sockets) and packets with such addresses would be neither routed correctly over the Internet (there is no route for ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96) nor understood by the recipient.

Comment: I found the answer to my question, `you cannot send packets to an IPv4 address if you don't have IPv4 yourself`. But I have some doubts about this: `access to a NAT64 translator which has IPv4`. Is there any NAT64 translator which has IPv6??

Comment: Yes, all of them. That's literally in the job description of a NAT64 gateway – it needs to interact with IPv6 clients on one side and IPv4 servers on the other.

Answer (score 0):

A pure IPv4 environment cannot use IPv6. Tunneling from IPv6 to
IPv4 is possible, but not the opposite.

Many VPNs support tunneling both IPv4 and IPv6 traffic.
Setting up the right VPN on your computer could provide
a solution for the problem, in effect enabling IPv6 for the
computer through the VPN.

Comment: Tunneling is possible in both directions – you can run a v4 (or dual-stack) tunnel across a v6 network just as easily as v6 over v4 – but having a tunnel that provides IPv4 connectivity pretty much makes the question moot...

Comment: Tunneling and NAT64 is out of the question. We suppose that the network is ipv6-only.

Comment: You might find a VPN that does the tunneling without installing more software than the VPN itself. I didn't do the market research for finding one.